# Why is $\Bbb R$ closed? (intuition)

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

So there are multiple ways of looking upon what a closed set is. Most intuitively it can be explained as a set which contains its own boundary.

But isn't the entire idea of $\Bbb R$ that is has no boundaries? No matter how far in one direction you go, you can always go much, much, much further. Wouldn't it make more sense to say that $\Bbb R$ does not have a boundary, therefore doesn't contain it (and therefore we still have $Cl \Bbb R = \Bbb R \cup \partial \Bbb R = \Bbb R \cup \emptyset = \Bbb R$, which is then implied to be a wrong definition of a closed set) and should it be much more logical to call $\Bbb R$ open instead of Clopen?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is both open and close. In any topology the whole space and the empty set are clopen, by definition.

Comment: Note that in topology a set isn't "just closed". It is closed _in something_ (namely, in some topological space). So for example, $\mathbb R$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, but it isn't closed in $\overline{\mathbb R}$ ([extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)).

Comment: What @Wojowu is the key in my opinion - and with that in mind, we want closed sets to coincide with their closure, what would the closure of $\Bbb R$ in $\Bbb R$ mean and/or look like?

Comment: @GFR I'm looking to understand the intuition. Isn't it counter intuitive that clopen even exists? Wouldn't it be more logical to assume a set to be open, and if and only if it contains its own borders it is closed, not open?

Comment: @Wojowu My mind is blown, how could $\bar{ \Bbb R }$ even exist? Infinity is not a number, how can it be in the same space as $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @CasperThalen, you seem to see a contradiction that I sincerely don't see. Your argument is "A set is closed if it contains its boundary. The boundary of $\Bbb R$ is $\emptyset$, *therefore* the first sentence fail sto describe a proprty of $\Bbb R$". But the part after "therefore" is not true. Indeed, $\emptyset\subseteq \Bbb R$, so $\Bbb R$ contains its boundary (in $\Bbb R$, because $\partial$ is an extrinsic object).

Comment: @CasperThalen a number is only what we define to be a number.  Under normal circumstances that does not include infinity, however in some circumstances such as in $\overline{\Bbb R}$ we *do* allow infinity.

Comment: I can see how I didn't get my point accross. My argument is since there is no boundary, $\Bbb R$ can't contain it. Therefore it must be open.

Comment: There is not "no boundary". The boundary is empty. And every set contains $\varnothing$.

Comment: @CasperThalen, regarding your comment about how clopen sets can even exist - it sounds to me like you're under the impression that "open" and "closed" are somehow opposites.  But they're not opposites at all.  Not sure if that's the root of your confusion though.

Answer (score 4):

By a definition of boundary
$$
\partial \Bbb{R} = \overline{\Bbb{R}}-\Bbb{R}^o=\Bbb{R}-\Bbb{R}=\varnothing
$$
So $\Bbb{R}$ has no boundary.

The most intuitive way to understand $\Bbb{R}$ being closed is the continuum of $\Bbb{R}$. Intuitively, any real number in the form of an infinite sequence of digits $\:\cdots .a_1a_2\cdots a_n\cdots\:$ coresponds (uniquely) to a point in the line, and vice versa. Therefore, any limit point in $\Bbb{R}$ will end up in $\Bbb{R}$, just like points on a line will stay in the line too.

Comment: Exactly, and if the definition of closed is that the set contains its own boundary, how can $\Bbb R$ be closed? It makes much more sense to me right now to just say it's open.

Comment: @CasperThalen Every set contains the empty set: $\varnothing\subseteq X$ for all $X$.

Comment: It is obvious that $\varnothing \subset \Bbb{R}$

Comment: I was making my case for why $\Bbb R$ should just be open as I understood @Wojowu 's comment on how a set is closed _in something_. I get it now, many thanks!